# How to use appsettings.local.json?

Tags: c#, appsettings

I have created an `appsettings.local.json` to my project. In my start up file - configure method, I have added the below code:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
      .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
      .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true) //load base settings
      .AddJsonFile("appsettings.local.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true) //load local settings
      .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true) //load environment settings
      .AddEnvironmentVariables(); 
    }
```

My application is still reading the original `appsettings.json` file and not the connection string from `appsettings.local.json`.
Did I miss out anything?

Answer (score 1):

`ConfigurationBuilder` used for create configuration by your own.
If you want do it, you should move your code to `Startup` constructor and after that add next line:

```
Configuration = builder.Build();
```

Where `Configuration` is name of your `IConfiguration` property.

If you still want inject `IConfiguration` to you `Startup` constructor you can use this code at you `IHostBuilder` at Program.cs:

```
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
            {
                builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.local.json", optional: true,
                        reloadOnChange: true) 
                    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json",
                        optional: true)
                    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            })
```

Please check `context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName` for you framework version: my sample for netcoreapp3.1.